Webpack Magic Comments - e.exports is empty when trying to import locale json files in production build
I'm using Webpack 5 and Vue 3 i18n.
I have an issue with magic comments and production builds where I'm awaiting an import for the locale file:
const { default: messages } = await import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "locale-[request]" */ `../locales/${newLocale}.json`
        );

        i18n.global.setLocaleMessage(newLocale, messages);

When compiling in production mode, I find all my locale json files are exported as empty modules like so:
"use strict";(self["wpJsonTestNamespace"]=self["wpJsonTestNamespace"]||[]).push([[12841],{43478:function(e){e.exports={}}}]);

Rather than containing any locale keys and values in the export.
I've tried a json loader, disabling babel, simplifying the webpack config.
I'd really love a hand if someone knows more on this or has seen it in the wild :)
If I convert the locale files to <locale code>.js they get exported correctly.
So my guess is something about them being json is not making webpack happy.

Turns out there appears to be a bug in webpack around lazy imports and json as reported in the date-fns and moment libraries.
Explicitly using the json-loader (which should automatically load JSON since webpack 2) corrects the problem as it forces Webpack to not tree shake the json output.
Disabling the optimization usedExports: false also fixed the problem, so it seems like some combination of Vue automatically tree-shaking json files because it thinks they aren't used
json-loader forces it to notice them again
So adding
configureWebpack: {
      module: {
          rules: [
              ...<other rules>
              {
                  test: /\.json$/,
                  loader: 'json-loader',
                  type: 'javascript/auto'
              }
           ]
      },
      output: ....
}


Also converting locales to js files works

Thanks for coming back days later to post your answer. You've saved me many, many hours of work. I don't know how I would have figured this out on my own. I'd love to see the moment and date-fns issues you mentioned in your answer, if you have those links.
